# Excel if one cell is filled place value in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Noob question.  I've tried several options from SO and elsewhere but I'm sure I'm missing something.

I have the following table:
[image]

I want to make a formula that does the following:

If the user puts any text in cell 1 = put a 5 in the final cell.

If the user puts any text in cell 2 = put a 4 in the final cell.

If the user puts any text in cell 3 = put a 3 in the final cell.

If the user puts any text in cell 4 = put a 2 in the final cell.

If the user puts any text in cell 5 = put a 1 in the final cell.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does "any text" mean just text, or also include numbers?

Comment: Good point. Anything at all.  Numbers letters special characters - anything.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one cell only is filled you can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(6-MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A1:E1),0),0)
```

If more than one cell is filled this formula will take the first filled cell.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel supports dynamic array formulas:

```
=IFERROR(6-XMATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A1:E1),0,-1),"")
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one formula you can use in the final cell to achieve the described behavior:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",5-MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:E1),0))
Breaking this down:
```

ISBLANK(A1) checks if Cell A1 is blank. Returns TRUE/FALSE.
ISBLANK(A1:E1) generates an array with TRUE/FALSE for each cell's blank status.
MATCH(TRUE,... gets position of the first non-blank cell.
Subtract this number from 5 to handle counting down from 5.
The IF statement handles case where all cells are blank.
So this will put 5 if A1 has text, 4 if B1 has text, etc. Down to 1 if E1 has text.

Comment: This doesn't return the desired results. Did you try it? Is this CrapGPT output?

Comment: "`MATCH(TRUE,... `gets position of the first non-blank cell." ... is false. It gets the position of the first *blank* cell.

Comment: "The IF statement handles case where all cells are blank" is also false. It only considers whether A1 is blank or not, which doesn't match the requirements.

Comment: "this will put 5 if A1 has text, 4 if B1 has text, etc. Down to 1 if E1 has text" is also false.

Comment: Sadly all the comments seem to be true.  Works like a charm for the first cell only.

Comment: BigBen, any ideas on what's the right way to go?